# Join in multiple mysql tables in php

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i really need help with these query.I have 3 tables with this structure

- Table users: id | fname | lname | email
- Table team: id | name | logo
- Table users_to_team : users_id | team_id

So now I want to display all users and their fname,lname,email if I just have team_id.I know that this can work with join in function but I'm weak when it comes to join in.

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
SELECT u.id, u.fname, u.lname, u.email FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_to_team ut on u.id = ut.users_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The query would be  :

```
Select fname,lname,email from  users, team, users_to_team where
users_id=users.id and team.id=team_id and team_id=*the team id that you have*
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested it and this works fine

```
SELECT users.fname, users.lname, users.email FROM users
INNER JOIN users_to_team ON users.id = users_to_team.user_id
WHERE users_to_team.team_id = 1
```

You put the team_id on the last line as you can see.